# Utilizar autocomplete de jquery UI en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, autocompletar

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en Node.js utilizando el framework express y como base de datos Oracle 10g.

Estoy utilizando el modulo de Oracle para Node.js y un ejemplo de guía hecho en PHP, he tratado de emular el ejemplo a Node pero aun no logro obtener el resultado del autocomplete, por ahora solo despliego los valores en el input mas no se auto completan los datos, ni se mantienen en el input, por favor si podrían guiarme para esto se los agradecería.

[Documentación oficial de OracleDB para Node.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb)

[Ejemplo de guía](https://obedalvarado.pw/blog/autocompletado-de-multiples-campos-usando-jquery-ajax-php-y-mysql/)

Mi codigo es el siguiente...

**Node:**

```
router.get('/list_user', authorize, function(req, res, next) {
    var connect = require('../connections/conn')(2);
    oracledb.getConnection(
        connect,
        function(err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return;
            }
            connection.execute("SELECT NOMBRE FROM USUARIOS", function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                } else {
                    var usuarios = [];
                    console.log("Complete...");
                    for (var index = 0; index < result.rows.length; index++) {
                        usuarios.push(result.rows[index].NOMBRE);
                    }

                    res.send(usuarios);

                }

                connection.close();
            });
        });
});
```

**La función para el autocomplete:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#vnombre").autocomplete({
        source: "/usuarios/list_user",
        type: "GET",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#vnombre').val(ui.item.NOMBRE);

        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group ui-widget">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 l " for="textinput">Nombre</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control 
       mayus" id="vnombre" name="vnombre">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ejemplo MySQL + Node.js:**

[Autocomplete in Node.js with MySQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w37db0gnf1Y&t=774s)

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución a esto, también debí aclarar que uso el motor de plantillas TWIG.

**Node js**

```
router.get('/list_user', authorize, function(req, res, next) 
{
var xxx=req.body.term;
var connect = require('../connections/conn')(2);
oracledb.getConnection(
    connect,
    function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return;
        }
        connection.execute("SELECT NOMBRE,APELLIDO FROM USUARIOS WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%"+xxx+"%'", function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            } else {
              res.send(result.rows);
            }
            connection.close();
        });
    });
    });
```

**La función para el autocomplete:**

```
 $("#vnombre).autocomplete({ //incio del autocomplete
 source:function (request,response){  //inicio del source
 $.ajax({       
 url: "/correspondencia/list_user" ,
 type: "POST",
 data:{
      term:request.term
    },
 timeout: 5000,
 success: function(data) 
    {                  //inicio del sucess
          response($.map(data,function(item){ //inicio del response
          return {
          label: item.NOMBRE,
          value: item.NOMBRE,
          ape: item.APELLIDO
                };
         }));                    
    }               //fin del sucess 
                  });    //fin del ajax 
                }, //fin fel source                                     
minLength:2,
select: function(event,ui){
  $("#vnombre").val(ui.item.value);
  $("#vapellido").val(ui.item.ape);
     } ,      
error: function() {
    console.log('process error');
    }
    }); //fin del autocomplete
```

**HTML**

```
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <div class="ui-widget form-group">
          <label for="ape" class="align_left">Apellido:</label>
          <input name="ape"  id="vapellido" class="form-control input-sm " placeholder="Apellido" type="text" required="required" autocomplete="off" >
          </div>
        </div>
```